# Python Dash without using external URLs for js

Tags: python, reactjs, plotly-dash

I am interested in using Dash to make some web applications for displaying data. I want to run this entirely locally without the references to unpkg.com/[...].  I realize that there is a relative package path  (pointing to local files) and an external package path (pointing to external locations), but I don't understand how I can switch from external to relative.

Where is this documented and/or does anyone have a solution for running Dash without the references to these packages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the [dash docs](https://plot.ly/dash/external-resources):

> ### Rendering dash apps offline
>
> The JavaScript and CSS bundles that are included in Dash component
>   libraries are hosted on the web (on the unpkg CDN) and in the Python
>   packages that you install. By default, dash serves the JavaScript and
>   CSS resources from the online CDNs. This is usually much faster than
>   loading the resources from the file system. However, if you are
>   working in an offline or firewalled environment or if the CDN is
>   unavailable, then your dash app itself can serve these files. These
>   files are stored as part of the component's site-packages folder.
>   Here's how to enable this option:
>
> ```
> from dash import Dash
>
> app = Dash()
>
> app.css.config.serve_locally = True
> app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour as of Dash 1.0.0 onward.
For the other way around, use `serve_locally=False` when initiating the Dash application. i.e.
`app = Dash(..., serve_locally=False)`

For reference, documentation is here: https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources